# Как находить R^2 и MAE metrics в Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
    inputs_train_torch = torch.from_numpy(inputs_train).float()
    inputs_test_torch = torch.from_numpy(inputs_test).float()
    outputs_train_torch = torch.from_numpy(outputs_train).float()
    outputs_test_torch = torch.from_numpy(outputs_test).float()
    
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(3, 24),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(24, 24),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(24, 1)
        )
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.09)
    for epoch in range(101):
        output = model(inputs_train_torch)
        loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_train_torch, (5760, 1)))
        print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'Loss train: ', loss.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    for epoch in range(101):
        output = model(inputs_test_torch)
        loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_test_torch, (2880, 1)))
        print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'Loss test: ', loss.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Я уже нашел MSE, нужно найти MAE и R^2

Answer (score 0):

Давайте вместе поищем. Гуглим сначала слово `MSELoss`, находим ссылку на документацию PyTorch на функцию [MSELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html). Переходим [на уровень выше](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html), ищем там по слову `MAE`, находим функцию [L1Loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.L1Loss.html) - это и есть `MAE` как написано в её описании (насколько я помню терминологию мера `L1` - это `MAE`, а `L2` - это `MSE`, почему в `Torch` нет однообразия в названиях функций я не знаю).

С `R^2` вот сложнее, в самом `PyTorch` я её сходу не нашёл, видимо нужно использовать например функцию [R2Score](https://pytorch.org/ignite/generated/ignite.contrib.metrics.regression.R2Score.html) из [PyTorch Ignite](https://pytorch.org/ignite/).

Comment: L1Loss работает спасибо. А как реализовать это? R2Score из PyTorch Ignite.

Comment: Ну, там написано как установить, если ещё не установлено `pip install pytorch-ignite` и дальше `from ignite.contrib.metrics.regression import R2Score`

Comment: А дальше что делать?)

Comment: А дальше вместо `torch.nn.MSELoss` использовать `R2Score`, если я правильно понял, что вы вообще хотите )

Comment: `criterion2 = R2Score
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.09)
for epoch in range(101):
        output = model(inputs_train_torch)
        R2 = criterion2(output, torch.reshape(outputs_train_torch, (5760, 1)))
        print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'R2 train: ', R2.item())
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()` попробовал так но не получилось

Comment: __минусующие господа__, не могли бы вы оставлять комментарии о том почему вы считаете данный ответ бесполезным?

Comment: как реализовать в коде R2score?

Comment: А скобки случайно забыты или нет? `criterion2 = R2Score()` должно быть

Comment: Поставил но потом вышла ошибка **TypeError: 'R2Score' object is not callable**